# Controlling color and width of HTML input box

Tags: html, css

The box diameter created by the code below is gray and about 1 pixel wide.  Is there any way I could make it 3 pixels wide and this color: `#DE2A00`?

```
<div class="usernameformfield"><input tabindex="1" accesskey="u" name="username" type="text" maxlength="35" id="username" /></div>
```

Comment: It would be helpful to see your current CSS for the HTML above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#username {
  border: 3px solid #DE2A00;
}
```